# Spock throwing NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/internal/AssumptionViolatedException

Tags: groovy, junit, spock

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/junit/internal/AssumptionViolatedException    at
>   org.spockframework.runtime.JUnitSupervisor.error(JUnitSupervisor.java:92)
>     at
>   org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.invokeRaw(BaseSpecRunner.java:318)
>     at
>   org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.invoke(BaseSpecRunner.java:297)
>     at
>   org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.runSpec(BaseSpecRunner.java:90)
>     at
>   org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.run(BaseSpecRunner.java:81)
>     at org.spockframework.runtime.Sputnik.run(Sputnik.java:63)  at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)

I have a simple test case that calls a method,

```
def 'some test for empty Lists'(){
        setup:
        List<Object> clauses=new ArrayList<Object>()

        when:
        String someString=builder.buildString(clauses, "someName", "AND");

        then:
        noExceptionThrown()
        someString==""
    }
```

Assume builder is injected via spring. I can't make out why this happens. It happens only for a few test cases.

Any help is much appreciated :) ***I use spock 0.6 with groovy 1.8.***

Comment: Does it happen during every testing process? Does it happen only where `noExceptionThrown` statement is used?

Answer (score 4):

### The solution for spock 1.0 with jUnit 4.12

As soon as I added **hamcrest-core-1.3** to my test classpath the error disappeared.

### What was the problem?

I observed the same error described in the question, but I managed to get **spock 1.0 groovy 2.4** to work with **junit-4.12**.

The problem was that **junit-4.12** depends on **hamcrest**. 
In fact `org.junit.internal.AssumptionViolatedException` implements the `interface` `org.hamcrest.SelfDescribing`.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same error with spock tests using a simple Eclipse java project with these versions:

- spock-core-1.0-groovy-2.3
- junit-4.12

The exception was thrown only when there was a test failures, but was working for the successful ones

I've found that it was a Junit version compatibility matter. i resolved it using junit-4.7 and also tested the following versions:

- junit-4.6 => ok
- junit-4.5 => ok
- junit-4.4 => ko
- junit-4.0 => ko

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

I had the same compatibility issue while trying to run my spocks in `STS:3.6.4` and JBoss Developer Studio Version: `7.1.1.GA`.

It was resolved using `junit-4.7` instead of `junit-4.12`

Other instructions can be found at https://code.google.com/p/spock/wiki/GettingStarted#Eclipse